# How do I modify the Magento Share Wishlist email template?

Tags: html, templates, email, magento, email-templates

I don't know where to find the "Share Wishlist" email template. I want to change the part where it says "Demo Store" to the proper store name. I also want to change it to a variable that points to the store name specified in the store configuration so that it automatically changes whenever the store name changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to the menu System > Transactional Emails.
2. Click "Add New Template".
3. Select "Share Wishlist" from the template list.
4. Click "Load Template" button.
5. Make your changes and give a new template name so that you may recognise it.
6. Save.
7. Go to the menu System > Configuration.
8. Under "Wishlist" select your new template.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using magento 1.41.  For me to modify the template of each individual items, I had to modify this file:

> $MAGENTO_PATH/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/items.phtml

Answer (score 2):

If you have to make a change to every template, you can do that by going to `$MAGENTO_PATH/app/design/locale/en_US/template/email/sales` all of the templates are in there. You can run a regex replace for whatever you're looking for. (The Demo Store name appears in multiple spots on some templates...)